# How do I obtain a default value when a tuple is empty in my Terraform template?

Tags: terraform

I have a `locals` block as follows:

```
locals {
  database_server_name = var.createDatabaseServer ? azurerm_postgresql_server.region[0].name : var.postgresqlServerName
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems like Terraform wants to evaluate the tuple (`region[0]`), despite not having to in every scenario:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on terraform/region/03-database.tf line 34, in locals:
  34:   database_server_name = var.createDatabaseServer ? azurerm_postgresql_server.region[0].name : var.postgresqlServerName
    |----------------
    | azurerm_postgresql_server.region is empty tuple
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I want above where a default value (`var.postgresqlServerName`) can be used in situations where the tuple is empty?

Comment: You may be stuck using the splat operator `*` workaround for this. It conforms to the old DSL syntax, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

From just the information you shared it's not clear how `var.createDatabaseServer` and `azurerm_postgresql_server.region` are related, and thus not clear what might cause evaluation of the first expression of the conditional in situations where it's not appropriate.

With that said, you may be able to get the answer you were looking for by directly testing for whether the situation you are expecting is true, rather than *inferring* it by testing another variable:

```
locals {
  database_server_name = (
    length(azurerm_postgresql_server.region) > 0 ?
    azurerm_postgresql_server.region[0].name :
    var.postgresql_server_name
  )
}
```

By directly testing how many elements there are in `azurerm_postgresql_server.region` you can avoid any situation where the condition and the first expression would disagree with each other.

Comment: Thank you so much for that tip, the length() check is exactly what I needed to avoid errors when evaluating this type of thing when it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take the logic out of the local and create the resource conditionally. Where you consume `local.database_server_name` could contain a `count` or `for_each` (which can contain other logic):

```
resource "azurerm_postgresql_server" "foo" {
  count = var.createDatabaseServer ? 1 : 0
  name = var.postgresqlServerName
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try()` beside conditional expression,

```
locals {
  database_server_name = (
    try(
      azurerm_postgresql_server.region[0].name,
      var.postgresql_server_name
    )
  )
}
```

Reference,
https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/9471971461651-ERROR-Invalid-index-on-empty-tuple

[Splat expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat) does not work because it returns an empty tuple instead of a default value, which is `var.postgresqlServerName`.